# android phonegap plugin for OCR

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ocr, local

I am looking for an android version of PhoneGap OCR plugin. Unfortunately I can't use the one for ocr-api-service because the OCR library is required to be local. Then I found this https://github.com/jcesarmobile/PhonegapOCRPlugin. And unfortunately it is only for ios. So I am just wondering if there is such plugin exists. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tesseract supports Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710123/how-can-i-use-tesseract-in-android) so you will have to [create a phonegap plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) yourself to wrap up the ocr feature.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it is not a pain to do so.

Comment: @user1775613 I would be that it is quite painful.

Comment: @esdotzed - Have you created/found any ocr plugin for android? If so, could you please share the details?