# Is there any way to extract text from image though OCR? any one kindly recommend example..thanks

Tags: android, ocr

I stuck in problem to extract text from image though OCR. could not find any example yet to. What i want to take image from camera and extract all text from image and display.Kindly anyone would recommend me fully example.

thanks.

Comment: you should try [this](https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview). A complete tutorial of getting text from image

Comment: Hi Aamir,  this post may help, unless you have already seen it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836136/android-ocr-library.

Comment: https://github.com/renard314/textfairy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android OCR Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836136/android-ocr-library)

Comment: thanks all of you let me check and get back to with response

Comment: @Vij it is an app i want code free

Comment: yes it is opensource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tesseract-ocr. Very effective tool. I haven't used tesseract in android.I guess you can get information in [this](http://opensourceforu.com/2016/08/23297/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710123/how-can-i-use-tesseract-in-android) links.